# Why does SQL 2008 Profiler indicate that Stored Procedure run from EF4 is in Master?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, profiler, sql-server-profiler

Using Entity Framework 4 with stored procedures and SQL Server 2008 SP1...  When running SQL Server Profiler (TSQL_SPs template), the lines that show my stored procedure call and its statements say that this happened in DatabaseID = 1 (Master) but it is actually happening in my application database.  The procedures execute properly and return the data, and they only exist in my application database, so why does Profiler mark those lines as being in Master?  Is this a bug in Profiler?

Note that running the same code against a SQL 2000 instance, Profiler correctly shows the application's database ID.

***UPDATE***:  I have now tested this on a new installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 and it still displays this as if it happened in Master.

***UPDATE 2***:  This has been logged to Connect at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/572246/profiler-reports-ef4-queries-as-occurring-in-master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contains youir connectionstring the option 'MultipleActiveResultSets=True'? If yes, try to remove it and look at sql profiler.

Comment: Yes, the work-around of changing the *MultipleActiveResultSets* option within the connection string from the default of True to False instead, causes Profiler to properly report the query executing in the application database.

Sounds like a bug to me, but I can live with this work-around.  **THANKS!!!**