# SQL Server Profiler showing EF queries against master database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-profiler

What am I missing here? The queries I see in SQL Server Profiler are all targeted against the master database, which makes it difficult to filter by database name ... which event or events should I be watching so I can filter by database name.

The bigger question, what exactly is going on here?

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using? I remember that in some previous version filtering by database name worked really strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove this 'MultipleActiveResultSets=True' from your EntityFramework connection

string

after that,  you can see the target database name show in the Profiler , instead of master.

In my option, maybe ADO.NET team want to make use the MultipleActiveResultSets feature to get

data from DB, so they have to access master.

MultipleActiveResultSets  is about raise one query and don't return all its result (like in foreach statement in LINQ) , and in the same time ,raise another  query to get another data in the same session.

By default, this behavior is not allowed by DB. SO.....

Comment: Please refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971781/why-does-sql-2008-profiler-indicate-that-stored-procedure-run-from-ef4-is-in-mas

Comment: if you [select the SP:CacheHit event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5405628/5661968) then the database name shows up

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get around this issue, including leaving MARS active by adding an application name to my connection string:

```
Data Source=database_server;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Trusted Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=MyDatabase;
```

Then you can filter on application name.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for SQL Server 2008 R2, in your trace properties, on the 'Events Selection' tab, check 'Show all columns'.  You should then be able to create a column filter based on DatabaseName.

I believe you'll have to pause or stop your trace to make these changes.

Answer (score 2):

As K Ivanov pointed out, having MARS (MultipleActiveResultSets) enabled will show the DatabaseName as master in SQL Profiler.  By setting this to false, it'll show the proper DatabaseName, but then you lose the ability to have MultipleActiveResults.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `LoginName` or `HostName` to filter in the profiler

Comment: That seems kind of "hackish" ... any idea why I can't just filter on the databasename?

Comment: you can filter on any column, how is DatabaseName any different than any of the others? as long as you are able to capture what you are executing and filtering out the rest of the traffic I call it solution

Comment: BTW, see if you have MultipleActiveResultSets=True in your connection string, setting it to False might solve the problem with the master DB execution, which is actually SQL Profile issue rather than EF problem

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, if I select the SP:CacheHit event, it now shows the queries against the correct database and I am able to filter by it. What is that event exactly?